# iOS9 does not load insecure resources from a secure page (SSL/HTTPS)

Tags: ios, http, ssl, uiwebview, ios9

I am trying to load a page into UIWebView on iOS9 using https:// URL. The page loaded includes CSS and images from an insecure server.

E.g. the page loaded: ***https**://www.example.com/* which includes stylesheet ***http**://www.example.com/style.css* and image ***http**://www.example.com/image.jpg*

Everything works if the original page is loaded via insecure connection (regular http). Everything works also on iOS8 both via HTTPS and HTTP.

I did set *NSAppTransportSecurity* to *NSAllowsArbitraryLoads* in application PLIST file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Though when loading the page via HTTPS, the images are loaded OK, but CSS files are not. Seems like *UIWebView* blocks loading insecure resources from a secure page.

Is there any setting of *UIWebView* that will allow to load CSS via insecure connection?

Comment: If you add an [HSTS header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security) the browser will automatically upgrade all HTTP links to your domain to HTTPS (but ideally you should fix the links too).

Comment: Have there been any new updates on this anyone?? Is it possible now to do this maybe with WKWebView or a new iOS tool?

Comment: @illis69, not that I know of. The requirement not to load insecure resources from secure pages is a reasonable one, so it won't probably be be changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not related to ATS. WebKit enforces a mixed content policy that disallows access to certain classes of "active" content (JS, CSS, etc) from being loaded over an insecure connection when the host page is being served over https.

If you examine your page in the Inspector you will see this being reported in the error panel.

---

Follow up: You can't turn off mixed content blocking. Allowing insecure CSS or JS reduces the security of the entire page to that of the least secure resource. The solution if you must load css/js over http is to load the entire page over http. That way the UI seen by the user correctly reflects the security of the content.

Comment: As a followup to the modified question: you can't turn off mixed content blocking. Allowing insecure CSS or JS reduces the security of the entire page to that of the least secure resource.

The solution if you must load css/js over http is to load the entire page over http. That way the UI seen by the user correctly reflects the security of the content.

Comment: As the answer does not allow me to solve the issue of loading insecure content from an insecure page, this does explain that it is impossible. Marked as a correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

In your info.plist you need to add the following App Transport Security keys:

```
NSAppTransportSecurity                                      Dictionary
    NSAllowsArbitraryLoads                                  Boolean       YES
    NSExceptionDomains                                      Dictionary    
        **YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE**                                Dictionary
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads              Boolean       YES
            NSIncludesSubdomains                            Boolean       YES
            NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads    Boolean       YES
```

Hopefully this should work for you.

Comment: So how it should work if inside of my page several links refer to and load some data from outside source that doesn't relate to added domain ?!

Comment: If you don't want t to use NTS, you can simply set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true in your Info.plist. Otherwise you will have to add all the domains you are linking to. Here's a good link which explains it in details http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/

Answer (score 5):

**App Transport Security** revised in iOS9 release. Now onwards your application is safe from un secure connection. And iOS forces to make secure connection. This can be conflict in your case.

From **[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW1)**

> If your app needs to make a request to an insecure domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file

So I think this can make an issue while loading `.css` file for web pages.

So give a try specify your domain in `info.plist` and check that `.css` files are loaded or not.

**Edit:**

---

Spotlight: You need to add more keys here in `info.plist`.

Look at this key `NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` this allows a service domain which is not controlled by developer and add an exception to Transport layer to by pass insecure resources.

The structure for adding keys for **App Transport Security** is below:

[image]

For more details and explanation about all keys check this note - [**App Transport Security Technote**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html)

Comment: Adding the domain to the exclusion list (`NSIncludesSubdomains`) did not help. the view still does not load insecure resources for a secure page.

Answer (score 4):

Below procedure enable me to open not secure content in WKWebView.

1. First I added **Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content = YES** and **Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES** in **App Transport Security Settings** dictionary in info.plist. [image]
2. I have added below wkwebview delegate method:

   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
       completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
   }

   For 2nd step don't forget to register delegate as:

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
   }

Comment: Bro, this is amazing, been looking for this for SO long, thank you. You Saved my day

Answer (score 2):

On Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

It has changed to

`App Transport Security Settings` > `Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content` > `YES`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I use webkit tool but i can't open the link that ssl not allow (some https links) and it's work on swift4 by this code (you must declare delegate before)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: currentAttach.fileUrl!)
    let req = URLRequest(url:url!)
    self.webView!.load(req)
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self

    }
}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate{

    //MARK:- WKNavigationDelegate
    //For Allow SSL https
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Strat to load")
        startLoading()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("finish to load")
        stopLoading()
    }

}
```