# SFSafariViewController crash: The specified URL has an unsupported scheme

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

My code:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "www.google.com") {
    let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(URL: url)
    safariViewController.view.tintColor = UIColor.primaryOrangeColor()
    presentViewController(safariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This crashes on initialization only with exception:

> The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported

When I use `url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")`, everything is fine.
I am actually loading URL's from API and hence, I can't be sure that they will be prefixed with `http(s)://`.

How to tackle this problem? Should I check and prefix `http://` always, or there's a workaround?

Comment: see this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577727/uiwebview-does-not-show-images-on-ios-9-and-safariviewcontroller-does-not-load

Comment: I checked that out, it isn't related. I am already allowing arbitrary loading. That issue is not allowing connection and not loading local html by SFSafariController.

Comment: Kind of makes you wish there were a `SFSafariViewController.canOpen(url:)`-ish way of checking supported urls.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check for availability of **http** in your `url` string before creating `NSUrl` object.

Put following code before your code and it will solve your problem (you can check for `https` also in same way)

```
var strUrl : String = "www.google.com"
if strUrl.lowercaseString.hasPrefix("http://")==false{
     strUrl = "http://".stringByAppendingString(strUrl)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a solution I mentioned in the question itself. I want to know if there are some workarounds or better way to tackle this?

Comment: @SahilKapoor As of now I can't find any better solution for it, if you could find it then also mention it for future reference

Comment: I recommend avoiding parsing the string by hand... unless you are working at the  RFCs level of the URL formatting. 

Use -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780352-scheme

Answer (score 45):

Try checking scheme of `URL` before making an instance of `SFSafariViewController`.

**Swift 3**:

```
func openURL(_ urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        // not a valid URL
        return
    }

    if ["http", "https"].contains(url.scheme?.lowercased() ?? "") {
        // Can open with SFSafariViewController
        let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        self.present(safariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Scheme is not supported or no scheme is given, use openURL
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

**Swift 2**:

```
func openURL(urlString: String) {
    guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else {
        // not a valid URL
        return
    }

    if ["http", "https"].contains(url.scheme.lowercaseString) {
        // Can open with SFSafariViewController
        let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(URL: url)
        presentViewController(safariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Scheme is not supported or no scheme is given, use openURL
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I did a combination of Yuvrajsinh's & hoseokchoi's answers.

```
func openLinkInSafari(withURLString link: String) {

    guard var url = NSURL(string: link) else {
        print("INVALID URL")
        return
    }

    /// Test for valid scheme & append "http" if needed
    if !(["http", "https"].contains(url.scheme.lowercaseString)) {
        let appendedLink = "http://".stringByAppendingString(link)

        url = NSURL(string: appendedLink)!
    }

    let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(URL: url)
    presentViewController(safariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: As sample code, I think adding `http` makes sense, but in the real world, maybe it should be `https`?

Answer (score 3):

Use WKWebView's method (starting iOS 11),

```
class func handlesURLScheme(_ urlScheme: String) -> Bool
```

Comment: Example of how you'd use this?

Comment: WKWebView.handlesURLScheme(url.scheme?.lowercased() ?? "")

Comment: handlesURLScheme returns true for ftp:// scheme, but then SFSafariViewController crashes with error `NSInvalidArgumentException - The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported.`

Answer (score -1):

you can add to

```
  NSString* webStringURL = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: webStringURL];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).