# how to allow both https and http on web view in iOS 10.2 and above

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, ios10.2

I am working on UIWebView and loading HTTPS url, but if it contains http within it then it does not open. Mainly i need to open mix content in UIWebView. I tried using "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" enabled, but no luck. My target iOS version is iOS 10.2 and above.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is called mixed content blocking, and the web view enforces it to increase user's security. This question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456848/ios9-does-not-load-insecure-resources-from-a-secure-page-ssl-https).