# WKWebView not loads http image in iOS 10 and above

Tags: ios, ios10, wkwebview

I am loading a `https` URL in `WKWebView` and inside that few images are coming from `HTTP` URL which is loading perfectly fine on enabling `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in `info.plist` file in iOS 9. But on iOS 10 and above it is not loading the `HTTP` images.  I read [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) and followed all possible way but no luck.

Comment: instead of enabling arbitrary loads try to use except domains if all data came form same unsecured site

Comment: Add an NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent exception key it allow to load http in iOS 10

Comment: @DSDharma, thanks for help, i tried with using except domains, and with "NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent" also but with no luck. :(

Comment: ensure that you have added NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in correct plist file . and plist contains only this **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** key.

Comment: In iOS 10 and later the value of [the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads] key is ignored if any of the following keys are present in your app’s Info.plist file:

NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia
NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent
NSAllowsLocalNetworking

Comment: @KKRocks, as per your suggestion i kept only NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in my plist file, and it is working in iOS 9 but not in iOS 10 and above :(

Comment: ensure that your plist is correct in which you have made this changes.

Comment: @KKRocks thanks for help. If i disable "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" then its not working in iOS 9. So with this i am sure that my info.plist is the correct one. But this change is not working in iOS 10 and above.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712228/3901620

Comment: @KKRocks, yes i verified as per link https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712228/3901620 and it is fine. I also read below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456848/ios9-does-not-load-insecure-resources-from-a-secure-page-ssl-https. Is it not supported in iOS 10 and above, having doubt.

Comment: give your webview your so we can check that.

Comment: webView = WKWebView (frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 50.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height-50), configuration: config)
            webView!.navigationDelegate = self
            webView!.uiDelegate = self
            webView!.scrollView.delegate = self
            view.addSubview(webView!)
            let urlStr = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:     .urlQueryAllowed)
        
            let m_url = URL(string: urlStr!)
            let m_url_request = URLRequest(url: m_url!,
        
            self.webView!.load(m_url_request)

Comment: @user3513902 Is this issue resolved? I am facing the same.

Loading below image on WKWebview through HTML Javascript:
    <img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/klipfolio/image/upload/v1500283193/pic_bulboff_to4zaq.png"  height="180">

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in `info.plist`,

```
NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent
```

and set its value as `YES`

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, i tried with "NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent", but still image is not loading in iOS 10 and above.

Comment: Ok. so try to add this in info.plist... Hope it would works.<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
 <dict>
  <key>api.unsecured-connection.net</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
   <true/>
  </dict>
 </dict>
</dict>

Comment: i tried with keeping <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict> <key>NSExceptionDomains</key> <dict> <key>api.unsecured-connection.net</key> <dict> <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key> <true/> </dict> </dict> </dict> but still it does not work. With keeping this in iOS 9 works fine but again in iOS 10 and above same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Allowing Insecure Connection to a Single Server**

fetching media from an insecure server use below

```
NSAppTransportSecurity
    NSExceptionDomains
        "media-server.example.com"
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = YES
```

> Apple warnings
>
> Important: Before implementing this exception, consider that a
>   seemingly-benign network request can cause security problems of the
>   sort that ATS is intended to mitigate. For example, fetching media
>   from an insecure server entails the following risks, among others: An
>   attacker can see the media file a user is accessing Your app’s attack
>   surface expands, for example, by allowing a bad actor to feed your app
>   a malicious file intended to trigger a buffer overrun Avoid this
>   connection type if possible.

The App Transport Security (ATS) keys are:

1. NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
2. NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia
3. NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent
4. NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
5. NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion

You can get more info from [NSAppTransportSecurity](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW44)