# UI WebView and WK WebView Navigation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

In my app, I am opening a URL using WK WebView. URL loads correctly, but if I click on some external links in the loaded URL it does not redirect to other websites.

For example

Following is my URL
https://www.urlaubstracker.de

In the above link, different holiday deals are linked to external websites. If I click on any button which redirects user to another website, app does not work or load the URL.

I tried using UI WebView and it is working perfectly fine. Could some one please point out what exactly I am missing here in my WK WebView.

Comment: Http is not a issue here, as in my app in info.plist I have already did "App Transport Security Settings - Allows Arbitrary Loads to YES".

Comment: Add   NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = YES may be it will help you.check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44795602/3937664

Answer (score 0):

1. First, enable ATS in your app.
2. Now, please try with this code.

   ```
   var webView: WKWebView?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
       webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
       let url = URL(string: "https://www.urlaubstracker.de")
       let req = NSURLRequest(url: url!)
       self.webView!.load(req as URLRequest)
       self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self
       webView?.navigationDelegate = self
       webView?.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
       webView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
       view.addSubview(webView!)
   }

   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, 
   decisionHandler: (@escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
   print("webView:\(webView) decidePolicyForNavigationAction:\(navigationAction) decisionHandler:\(decisionHandler)")


       switch navigationAction.navigationType {
       case .linkActivated:
           if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
               webView.load(navigationAction.request)
           }
       default:
           break
       }

       decisionHandler(.allow)
   }
   ```

Comment: @Waleed Asif, I had tried like this and it is working fine.

Comment: I used exactly your code, but its not working. It loads the URL correctly but whenever I click on the link which should open another website, nothing happens and thats my issue. Using UI Webview its working fine bt not with WK web view that I would like to use as it is recommended by Apple. Could you please help here

Comment: Could you please help me to replicate the same?  I have loaded your website with Webkit. Now, where should I click?

Comment: For example in this URL,https://www.urlaubstracker.de/italien-kalabrien-residence-san-leo/                                                                                                If you try to click on "flug", Wk Webview does not open it (clicking "flug" user is taken on a other website if I use UI Webview).

Comment: @waleed Asif, I have updated my answer please look up to this.

Answer (score 0):

try using
[WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate)

also switch to SafariViewController