# WKWebView and Amazon Affiliate image src

Tags: ios, swift4, wkwebview

I am using amazon affiliate image links in my website that is then converted to an App using the WKWebView in Swift 4.

The Amazon affiliate link works perfectly fine if I access the webpage directly from Safari or any other browser. But the image is not showing  in the app that is using WKWebView: a small question mark icon is displayed instead, and when I click the small icon it opens the right amazon link.

Here is my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!


    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 1
        let url = URL(string: "http://myurl/")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

        // 2
        let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView.reload))
        toolbarItems = [refresh]
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        title = webView.title
    }
}
```

Here is the Amazon affiliate link that I have in my HTML:

```
<a target="_blank"  href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KEBYK88" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img border="0" src="https://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&MarketPlace=US&ASIN=B00KEBYK88&ServiceVersion=20070822&ID=AsinImage&WS=1&Format=_SL160_&tag=questionrs-20" ></a><img src="https://ir-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=questionrs-20&l=am2&o=1&a=B00KEBYK88" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
```

Note that it has an img tag:

```
<img border="0" src="https://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&MarketPlace=US&ASIN=B00KEBYK88&ServiceVersion=20070822&ID=AsinImage&WS=1&Format=_SL160_&tag=questionrs-20" >
```

If I put this img tag directly in my HTML the image is still not shown via the WKWebView in the app (but shows fine if I open the website in any browser directly)

If I open the image src in the browser it is converted to:

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ZIpVTW8-L._SL160_.jpg
```

And, if I put this new URL in the src, WKWebView can display it.

Is there any possibility to have WKWebView display the original image URL?

Comment: You are loading `WKWebView` with a internal phone url or a external website? Also see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456848/ios9-does-not-load-insecure-resources-from-a-secure-page-ssl-https

Comment: The link you provided helped; I added Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content = YES and Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES in App Transport Security Settings dictionary in info.plist and all worked. Please include this as an answer so I can give the 200 bounty after 24 hours restriction is passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content = YES` and `Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES` in App Transport Security Settings dictionary in `info.plist`

[iOS9 does not load insecure resources from a secure page (SSL/HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456848/ios9-does-not-load-insecure-resources-from-a-secure-page-ssl-https)

Comment: both my URL and image link are https (also, image URL redirects to another https URL), but still the above solved the problem. Thank you.