# Images not showing in capacitor svelte app

Tags: javascript, svelte, capacitor

I'm trying to port my svelte app into capacitor to make it a mobile app. I was able to create an android build and run it on my phone and on my android emulator, the problem is that the images are not showing.

[image: android image]

To give you some context my app is pretty much a random image generator, pulling a different image from a remote url every time you click a button. The images are showing on the web no problem, but for some reason in my phone and on android emulator they don't work.

I don't know if this is relevant but the images come from an http address and not https, I think the issue is probably to do with permissions of some kind but I don't know what configuration to change. This is my `capacitor.config.ts` file:

```js
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.moviesapp.chrispoulsen',
  appName: 'movies-app',
  webDir: 'build',
};

export default config;
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, neither Android nor iOS allow `http` connections anymore.
You have to use `https` connections or configure your app to allow `http` traffic.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, could you elavorate on how to allow http traffic?

Comment: I was able to change the request to https and it worked! But I would also like to know how to allow http requests for future reference

Comment: Well, that's not really Capacitor specific and there are several answers already in stack overflow. 
Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted
iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465110/19796642

Comment: Okay, so there's no way to configure that directly from capacitor?

Comment: no, there is no capacitor configuration for this since it's not a capacitor thing but a OS thing, at some point Apple and Google decided http was not secure and they will not load http content unless the app is explicitly configured to do it